# Cast all columns of a table except some

Tags: sql, postgresql, hash, casting

In Postgres I am taking each row of the table and adding a new column that is an md5 hash of that rows contents.

```
alter table my_table add hash_col text;
update my_table set hash_col =md5(cast((my_table.*) as text));
```

My only issue is how would you cast all columns except 1 or 2? Right now the cast function is:

```
cast(my_table.*)
```

Psuedo-code for my desired outcome would be:

```
cast(my_table.* EXCEPT col1, col2)
```

Comment: or do it right and write all columns down in the quer, and don't search for a quick way out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "All columns except these columns"

Unfortunately, SQL has no way of saying *"all columns of the table except these ones"*. It can just say *"all columns of the table"* with `SELECT *`.

You ***could*** do something similar with `jsonb`:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(my_table) - '{col1, col2}' FROM my_table;
```

So this works:

```
UPDATE my_table t
SET    hash_col = md5((to_jsonb(t.*) - '{col1, col2}'::text[])::text);
```

Related:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69658/3684)

**But** that's considerably **more expensive** than spelling out columns to be included. And the hash value, while still distinct per given set of values, is based on the (longer) text representation of the `jsonb` value. And if you change the table definition of `my_table` later, this is likely to break existing hash values. So, it's typically also **less safe** than spelling out columns to be included.

#### Proper solution

Spell out remaining columns. Make repeating the (possibly lengthy?) list of columns simpler and safer by encapsulating the hash generation in a function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_myhash(col3 int, col4 int, col5 text)
  RETURNS uuid
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE COST 25 PARALLEL SAFE AS 
'SELECT md5(textin(record_out(($1,$2,$3))))::uuid';
```

Adapt column names and types to your actual list.
Then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD hash_col uuid;
UPDATE my_table SET hash_col = public.f_myhash(col3, col4, col5);
```

While being at it, I converted the MD5 hash to type `uuid`, which is typically superior in every way. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

If you don't actually *need* MD5, consider `hash_record_extended()` instead.  Simpler and faster. But it generates "only" a `bigint` hash.
And maybe an expression index is good enough and you don't even need to add another column?
See (!):

- **[Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)**